# SQL Server 2008 Try/Catch parameter names and values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, try-catch

I have searched, but was not able to find how to get the parameters names and values of a stored procedure from the catch section of a try/catch in SQL server 2008.

I know how to get the parameters for example:

```
SELECT  parm.name AS Parameter
        ,typ.name AS [Type]
FROM    sys.procedures sp
        JOIN sys.parameters parm ON sp.object_id = parm.object_id
        JOIN sys.types typ ON parm.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id
WHERE   sp.name = OBJECT_NAME(@@procid)
```

Basically what I am looking for is the SP that executed with parameters and values so I can log and troubleshoot.  Something like:

```
wsp_GetUser_s @UserID = 123, @UserName = 'juser'
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but if you are talking about a try catch block within an SP, say SP1, and you want to log the params that were passed to SP1, how could you not known the param names and values?

Comment: I don't want to have to code all those manually if possible, it would be nice to make a snippet that dynamically does this.  Say a new parameter is added, I would rather not change the code in the catch.  Also when generating SPs it would be nice to not have to code all that out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature in Microsoft SQL Server's **catch** block to automatically log what parameters were passed in to the database object.

If you want to know what parameters are passed in, I recommend running a trace or using Extended Events.

If neither of those options are feasible I recommend creating a table to store this information. One column can have the Stored Procedure name and another column can have the parameters. The parameters column can contain a comma delimited list of whatever parameters were passed into the stored procedure.

Example:

```
create table dbo.Parameters ( 
RowID int identity(1,1),
StoredProcedure varchar(255),
Parameters varchar(max)
)

create proc dbo.wsp_GetUser_s  ( 
@UserID int,
@UserName varchar(255)
)
as
begin try
select *
from dbo.Users
where UserID = @UserID
and UserName = @UserName

-- We'll only log to the Parameters table if we don't find a match
if @@rowcount < 1
begin
RAISERROR ('Did not find user. Logging passed parameters to dbo.Parameters table', -- Message text.
               16, -- Severity.
               1 -- State.
               );
end

end try
begin catch
-- This could be moved into the catch block if you wanted to log this for all calls and not only when there is no match found for the passed in parameters.
insert into dbo.Parameters ( StoredProcedure, Parameters)
select 'wsp_GetUser_s', '@UserID=' + @UserID + ', @UserName=' + @UserName
end catch
```